# SQL server trigger after insert auto increment of an int value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a Client table with fields ClientID, UniqueId, Name, Address, etc. UniqueID, Name, Address and other info are populated from the UI. I want to use a trigger to auto populate the ClientID field (not seeded, not null) in SQL server. I have tested some codes (see below) but they don't seem work. any suggestions?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateClientID]
ON [dbo].[Client] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Max INT;
    DECLARE @Increment INT;

    SET @Max = 0;
    SET @Increment = 1; 

    SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM inserted

    SELECT @Max = MAX(ClientID)
    FROM Client

    WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM #temp WHERE ClientID IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #temp
        SET ClientID = @Max + @Increment
        SET @Increment = @Increment + 1
    END

    UPDATE c
    SET ClientID = t.ClientID
    FROM Client c
    INNER JOIN #temp t on c.UnqiueID = t.UniqueID
END
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if more than one row is inserted at a time?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If that's case, I can loop through records in the inserted table and update one by one.

Comment: If you are just going to use an incremental integer I would strongly suggest using an identity instead of trying to roll your own. There are a lot of challenges with concurrency which the identity has already figured out. Don't do this to yourself. Keep it simple and use an identity.

Comment: So what is wrong with your current code?   Are you getting an error?   What is the error?

Comment: Thanks Sean. The problem is that the table is already existed and the ClientID is already populated.

Comment: OK, i made it work after I made some change on the SQL. thanks every body.

Comment: I modified the original code to be able to handle multiple rows inserted at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you may be able to benefit in this situation by using a sequence. See
[Create Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff878091.aspx)